# Finding a person with no siblings in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write Prolog code that calculates how the fortune of man divided between his family members based on Islamic inheritance rules.
One of the cases is that, if a daughter has no siblings from her father she has the right for half of his fortune.
So my question is how to set a rule that tests if the daughter has no siblings from her father.

```
half(X,Y) :-
    father(Y,X),
    female(X),
    sibling(What to do here?),
    read(N),F is N*0.5, write(F).


male(ahmed).
male(adel).
male(hamza).
male(marwan).

female(sara).
female(lobna).
female(ghada).
female(aisha).
female(noor).

parent(aisha,sara).
parent(aisha,hamza).
parent(aisha,ghada).
parent(adel,sara).
parent(adel,hamza).
parent(adel,ghada).
parent(adel,lobna).
parent(marwan,noor).

sibling(X,Y):-parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), X\=Y.
father(X,Y):-male(X), parent(X,Y).
mother(X,Y):-female(X), parent(X,Y).
brother(X,Y):-male(X), (sibling(X,Y);sibling(Y,X)).
sister(X,Y):-female(X), (sibling(X,Y); sibling(Y,X)).
half(X,Y):-father(Y,X),female(X),sibling(X,_),read(N),F is N*0.5, write(F).
```

Comment: The easiest would probably be a second predicate like `sibling/2` that checks if `Z` is male. It's better design to add `N` and `F` as parameters of `half/2` and skip the `read/1` and `write/1`.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you need `(sibling(X,Y);sibling(Y,X))` in your `brother/2` and `sister/2` predicates. Your `sibling/2` predicate already handles the symmetrical case. Also, in `sibling/2`, I'd suggest using `dif(X,Y)` rather than `X \= Y`.

Comment: If you reason it out: a person has no siblings if `F`is their father and `F` has no other children, right? So, `no_father_siblings(Person) :-
    father(Father, Person),
    \+ (father(Father, Sibling), Sibling \== Person).`

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd add a few more rules to make the intent clearer - e.g.:

```
daughter(D,P) :- parent(P,D), female(D).
```

And you can create a rule which specifically checks to see if someone has any siblings:

```
has_sibling(X) :- sibling(X,_).
```

You can then write a rule called, say, `eligible_half\2` to check for eligibility --

```
eligible_half(D,F) :- father(F,D), daughter(D,F), \+ has_sibling(D).
```

It looks like you've done the *opposite* of this in your definition of `half/2` at the bottom of your code, though - your definition requires that the daughter *does* have a sibling.

At any rate, this means you can write a definition of `half\2` which doesn't itself define any logical rule, but just checks that `eligible_half\2` holds and does some I/O:

```
half(D,F):-
  eligible_half(D,F),
  read(N), number(N), HalfN is N*0.5, write(HalfN).
```

And as @lurker noted, you don't need to have the symmetric calls to `sibling\2` in your definition of `brother\2` and `sister\2`. Hopefully that's of use.